# Question about Spanning Column and Rows in Spool in SQL-Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

Is it possible to colspan and rowspan when spooling into a .xls file?

like using a colspan and rowspan in html <table< tags?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, Oracle SQL Developer will return the simple excel file generated from the output of your query, you can't tell it to format the output combining cells.

Depending on your use case, you might be able to program a PL/SQL function and/or procedure to generate the html code of your output, and then write that html code to a file in a directory accessible from the Oracle Database, but you'll have to program the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I'm gonna use other means, instead. I'm just making sure if there is or there is not a way.